# Reading a csv file into a struct in C using scanf

Tags: c, csv, struct, scanf, binary-search-tree

I'm having an issue reading in from a csv data file into in to a node for a binary search tree in C. It seems as though none of the data is actually being read into the struct. The code I am using now is just trying to read a single line of data from the csv file before I can scale it up to read the whole thing, but even with this I am not getting the results. I am aware there are probably many large issues in this code as I am not extremely competent with the language however any insight would be appreciated.

```
typedef struct{
  struct bst_t *left;
  struct bst_t *right;
  data_t data;
} bst_t;
```

Here is my read function

```
void readdata(bst_t node){
  while(
  scanf("%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],
   %[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,] ,[^,],%[^,],%[^,] ... ) == 14);
}
```

Here is my print function

```
void printdata(bst_t node){
  printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s \n"...);
}
```

however my output is simply:

```
-bash-4.1$ print

,,,,,,,,,,.,(@,,▒
```

Another additional problem that I am yet to face is that some of the data within the file will have commas within an entry, how would I go about 'ignoring' these commas so they appear as data and not a separator in the file?

Once again any help at all would be much appreciated.

EDIT: This is where I call the functions: (ie main)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
bst_t node;
readdata(*node);
printdata(node);
return 0;
```

}

New Compiler code

```
print.c: In function 'main':
print.c:37: error: invalid type argument of 'unary *' (have 'bst_t')
print.c: In function 'readdata':
print.c:56: error: request for member 'node' in something not a structure     or union
```

Here is the complete code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define MAXSTRING 128


typedef struct{
  struct bst_t *left;
  struct bst_t *right;
  struct data_t data;
} bst_t;

void readdata(bst_t *node);
void printdata(bst_t node);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bst_t node;
    readdata(&node);
    printdata(node);
    return 0;
}


void readdata(bst_t *node){
  while(
  scanf("%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,] \n",...) == 14)

}
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you are calling these two functions.

Comment: Remember that in C all arguments to functions are pass *by value*, i.e. they are *copied* and the function only have a copy to work on. Now think about what happens when you modify a copy of a structure, but the original still stays unmodified.

Comment: And, you get a **Gold Star** for actually **validating the return** of `scanf`. You will do well. Only other suggestion would be to declare a buffer (something large enough times 2) and then read an entire line at a time (e.g. `while (fgets (buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) { if (sscanf (buffer, "%....", node.data.ID, ...) == 14) ... }` That way you can validate both (1) read of the line; and (2) the parse of the line into variables. Granted it is a wash, but given an *input* or *matching* failure, you have read the complete line and can continue to the next.

Comment: I have updated with the main code

Comment: You need: `readData(&node)` to make a pointer of. However, readData needs to accept a pointer as well, as denoted in given answer... `*node` is the other way round: If you *already have* a pointer, then you get the value of. Example: `int n; int* p = &n; *p = 7;` will effectively assign 7 to `n`.

Comment: Updating it to readData(&node) still leaves me with the second compiler error however, how would I fix this?

Comment: Fields in CSV files can contain commas.  "Like, this"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The read function only updates the local variable `node` it receives by value as an argument. You must pass a pointer to a newly allocated structure:

```
void readdata(bst_t *node) {
    while (scanf(" %[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],[^,],%[^,],%[^,]",
                 node->data.ID, node->data.name, node->data.sex,
                 node->data.height, node->data.weight, node->data.team,
                 node->data.NOC, node->data.games, node->data.year,
                 node->data.season, node->data.city, node->data.sport,
                 node->data.event, node->data.medal) == 14) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

You would call this function this way from `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bst_t node;
    readdata(&node);
    printdata(node);
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that this function is unsafe: it does not protect against buffer overflows.

Note also that it cannot handle empty fields, nor fields with embedded commas.

To parse the input correctly, you need a hand coded parser that handles special cases and provides precise error reports.

**EDIT:** The source code you posted has a syntax error:

```
               node->data.event->node.data.medal) == 14)
```

It should read:

```
               node->data.event, node->data.medal) == 14)
        continue;
```

You should format your code more readably, by indenting statements by 4 spaces and inserting spaces around binary operators and after `,`.

Try this version of `readdata`: (copy and paste from the web page)

```
void readdata(bst_t *node) {
    while (scanf(" %[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],[^,],%[^,],%[^,]",
                 node->data.ID, node->data.name, node->data.sex,
                 node->data.height, node->data.weight, node->data.team,
                 node->data.NOC, node->data.games, node->data.year,
                 node->data.season, node->data.city, node->data.sport,
                 node->data.event, node->data.medal) == 14) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add a `space` before the first `" %[^,].."` and remove the `'\n'` from the end to protect against a non-POSIX file ending.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: good suggestion, although a non-Posix file ending would not pose a problem. Skipping initial whitespace instead of trailing whitespace allows better interactive testing as lines can be processed as they are typed.

Comment: As string length is given as macro, we could have patterns like `"... %" #MAXSTRINGBASE "[^,] ..."` with macro defined as maximum length without terminating null character and have `#define MAXSTRING (MAXSTRINGBASE + 1)` to get arrays set up correctly (of course, base must not be a calculation for having this working correctly...).

Comment: @Aconcagua: unfortunately, your suggestion does not work: the stringize operator  only works in a macro expansion and would expand to `"(MAXSTRINGBASE + 1)"`, not the actual value. The format string could be constructed with `snprintf` prior to using it with `fscanf()`, but this only solves part of the problem.

Comment: I have tried to update my code to implement this but get a compiler error as shown in the original post (unsure how to format comments).

Comment: @chqrlie The other way round: `#define MAXSTRINGBASE 7`, which is stringified nicely, and  `char ID[MAXSTRING]` then gets resolved to `char ID[7 + 1]`...

Comment: @Aconcagua: yes, but you do need a macro to stringize `MAXSTRINGBASE` when constructing the format string: `"%" S(MAXSTRINGBASE) "[^,],"...` and the format string still does not handle empty fields.

Comment: @AdamPatterson: you would call `readdata` with a pointer to the structure: `readdata(&node);`

Comment: When calling it like this I still get the second compiler error (request for member node something not in a structure). I suspect this might be due to how I defined the data struct within the bst struct? but when I change that to
`struct data_t data;` I get rid of that error but get a new compiler error
`print.c:28: error: field 'data' has incomplete type` Any advice?

Comment: @AdamPatterson: you have a syntax error. Answer updated.